# how to ignore stdin input inside a script

Tags: linux, shell

I have a program "myprogram" and it waits for a enter key when run on console. After we press somekey it exits. I want to run this myprogram in background and ignore stdin input.

I have a smaple script,

sample.sh script

```
------
./myprogram &
exit 0
------
```

but when I run,

%sh sample.sh

some how myprogram gets some inputs from stdin and exits.. I want to stop it from getting any input from stdin so even after sample.sh exits myprogram continue to run.

Please suggest how I can update sample.sh script to achieve this.

Answer (score 5):

You can connect the program's standard-input to `/dev/null`:

```
./myprogram < /dev/null &
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it,

% ./myprogram < /dev/null & 
this works on a console terminal 

but when run it from inside my script it doesnot work