# Bash script stops execution on password promt

Tags: git, bash, shell

I have some Git repos that I need to update on regular basis. So I wrote a bash script as simple as

```
cd /repo1/path
git fetch --all

cd /repo2/path
git fetch --all
...
```

This script is run via a cron job. Authorization in Git is done via SSH. The problem here is that from time to time one or another repo rejects the certificate and thus prompts for a password (this is an issue of repo management which not addressed in the question). Once my script meets such a repo it just stops and (I guess) waits for password input, so all repos that go after it don't get updated.

The question is how to handle such situations - one failing repo shouldn't prevent others from being updated.

Comment: Do them all in the background `git fetch --all &`

Comment: @User112638726, won't I end with lots of tasks hanging in the background?

Comment: Yeah if they hang, but you can close any still open at the end of the script

Comment: use expect query to provide password or any other input in runtime.

Comment: @User112638726, could you please suggest the best way to do this?

Comment: Would this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13080680/6309) help?

Comment: @svz Added an answer.

Comment: @User112638726, sorry, I can't see your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use something like this.

For this example i have used sleep instead of git to display how it works better

```
#!/bin/bash

PIDS=()             # Make pid array

cd /repo1/path              #Go to dir
sleep 20 &                  #Command
x=$!                        #Save Pid
PIDS+=($x)                  #Add to pid array
Command[$x]="$(pwd)"        # Add to Command array(will contain failed dirs)

cd /repo1/path              #Same yo
sleep 20 &
x=$!
PIDS+=($x)
Command[$x]="$(pwd)"

cd /repo3/path
sleep 1 &                       #This one will exit before next part to show it doesn't
                                #appear in output
x=$!
PIDS+=($x)
Command[$x]="$(pwd)"

sleep 2                       # Literally here just so previous command finishes
                              #(not needed in a real script)

for i in "${PIDS[@]}";do      #Loop through the PIDS
        if ps -ef | grep -v "grep" | grep "$i" > /dev/null 2>&1 ;then
        #Check they're running, dump output
                kill "$i"                    #Kill running ones
                wait "$i" 2>/dev/null        # Suppress output
                echo "${Command[${i}]}" Failed    # echo failed dirs
        fi 
done
```

#### Output

```
/repo1/path Failed
/repo2/path Failed
```